# Using ldap with base64 encoded dn's in Alfresco

Tags: ldap, base64, alfresco

I'm using our LDAP (it is AD really) with Alfresco 5 CE and everything working ok,

but now I need to get only users from one specific OU.

And this OU has non-ASCII symbols, so it is base64 encoded, but how can I pass this base64 to alfresco configs? Any way to use it as usersearchbase or in filter?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try the normal Java ldap syntax for this?

Comment: You mean like ldap.synchronization.userSearchBase=OU=<non-ASCII>,DC=...,DC=... ? Yes, I tried this in Alfresco-global.properties
I also tried quoted "" and things like "dn:: <base64-encoded string>" with different "escaping"

Comment: " OU has non-ASCII symbols, so it is base64 encoded", So if something has non-ASCII it's autmatic base-64. have you manually converted it to see if it's working with like an online base64 decoder?